# JSON: use deserializing name different than serializing name json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have one class **`User`**, I received JSON (for User class) from system1 and I should read info , validate then forward to system2, I can't touch these 2 systems, the problem is the names of keys are different, I want to differentiate between deserialized and serialized name
received JSON is :

**`{"userId":"user1","pwd":"123456","country":"US"}`**

**`"{"username":"user1","password":"123456","country":"US"}"`**

But the sent should be like this

I am using Gson lib, and this is my code:

### User class:

```
class User implements Cloneable {

    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username ;
    
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password ;
    
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country ;

}
```

### TestJson class

```
class TestJson {

    private static GsonBuilder gsonBuilder;
    private static Gson gson;

    public static Object fromJson(String json, Class clz) {
        gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, clz);
    }

    public static String toJson(Object obj) {
        gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        String json = gson.toJson(obj);
        return json;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String json2 = "{\"userId\":\"user1\",\"pwd\":\"123456\",\"country\":\"US\"}";
        User user = (User) TestJson.fromJson(json2, User.class); 
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        User u = new User("user1","123456","US");
        String json1 = TestJson.toJson(u);
        System.out.println(json1);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: In your main method you specify the json string with its key for user id = 'userId', why not setting the key to 'userName'?

Comment: this is the received JSON

Comment: I want to differentiate between deserialized name and serialized name

Answer (score 7):

If there are alternative names of field just use `alternate` param of @[SerializedName](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

```
public class User {

   @SerializedName(value="username", alternate={"userId", "useriD"})
   private String username ;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Used the keys listed in the alternate param to populate the fields in the java class and the value param to construct the JSON. Brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

You can create custom serializer/deserializer for this purpose.

Serializer:

```
public class UserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<User> {
    @Override public JsonElement serialize(User obj, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        ..........
    }
}
```

Deserializer:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
    @Override public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ...........
    }
}
```

and to create Gson instance:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserSerializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

## Example

Edit: this is an example of a custom deserializer which might fit into your need. We don't need a custom serializer in this case.

Add this `UserDeserializer.java`:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        User user = new User(obj.get("userId").getAsString(), obj.get("pwd").getAsString(), obj.get("country").getAsString());
        return user;
    }
}
```

Replace your `fromJson` implementation with this (I use generic to avoid the need for casting when calling `fromJson`):

```
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> clz) {
    gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
    gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return gson.fromJson(json, clz);
}
```

Comment: how can i select the deserialization name?, there is @serializedName for serialization.

Comment: You don't need to use annotation. See my edited answer.

Comment: Try Jackson in that case

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of would be to have a custom Adapter or deser to a JsonObject and then map it to your User.

With [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson) you can create two instances of Genson, one for deserialization and another one for serializaiton. The one used in deserialization could be configured with renamed properties [like that](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/#filterrename-properties).

```
// you can also precise that you want to rename only the properties from User class
Genson genson = new GensonBuilder()
  .rename("username", "userId")
  .rename("password", "pwd")
  .create();

User user = genson.deserialize(json, User.class);
```

Comment: I am using Gson, not Genson